# How to merge code back to Github using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to merge code back to github with Jenkins pipeline. The script I have now complains that it is not a git repo.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker-agent' }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout Git'){
            steps {
                dir('repo1') {
                    git credentialsId: 'xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx',
                    branch: "master",
                    url: 'https://github.com/repo/repo1.git'
                }
                dir('repo2') {
                    git credentialsId: 'xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx',
                    branch: "master",
                    url: 'https://github.com/repo/repo2.git'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Environment Setup'){
            steps {
                sh 'pip3 install --user -r superloop/requirements.txt'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Run program'){
            steps {
                sh 'python3 main.py'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Prepare files to sync'){
            steps {
                dir('repo2') {
                    sh 'git add .'
                    sh 'git commit -m "Updates"'
                    sh 'git push origin master'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message from console output:

```
+ git add .
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How do I commit/merge code back to repo from pipeline?